# what can you do with IAM roles that you cannot do with IAM groups?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have read the documentation about IAM roles and IAM groups but I am missing something simple: I don't understand what you can do with IAM roles that you cannot do with IAM groups.

In other words, considering these alternatives:

- Using IAM groups, I grant a group permissions to perform certain actions, and then when I want a user to be able to perform those actions, I grant them membership in that group
- Using IAM roles, I grant a role permissions to perform certain actions, and then when I want a user to be able to perform those actions, I grant them permission to assume that role

What specifically is it that you can achieve with the second method, that you cannot achieve with the first method?

Answer (score 0):

- An **IAM User** is given a set of credentials for authentication. It can be assigned permissions. It is used either by people or by applications to call AWS services.
- An **IAM Group** is a *collection* of IAM Users. Permissions allocated to the IAM Group will apply to all IAM Users *within* the group.
- An **IAM Role** has a set of permissions, but no credentials. It is used by having an IAM User **assume** the role, which then provides a set of **temporary credentials** that can be used to access a service.

For example:

- `User1` is an IAM User with permission to launch an Amazon E2 instance. They can use their credentials to authenticate to AWS and request that an instance is launched. However, they do not have permission to Terminate the EC2 instance.
- `Admin-Role` is an IAM Role that has permission to Terminate EC2 instances.
- `User1` calls `AssumeRole()` on `Admin-Role`. If they have permission to do this, they will receive back a set of temporary credentials.
- `User1` then uses these credentials to call `TerminateInstances()`. In doing so, they use the temporary credentials to send the request, rather than their own credentials.

Similarly:

- `Lambda1` is an AWS Lambda function
- `Lambda-Role` is an IAM Role that is associated with the `Lambda1` function. The role has been granted permission to access Amazon S3.
- When the `Lambda1` function, the Lambda service automatically Assumes `Lambda-Role` and provides those credentials to the Lambda function so that it can call S3.

Notice that in this second example, the Lambda function does not have credentials itself. Rather, the AWS service assumes the Role on its behalf and provides the credentials. This is identical to the way that IAM Roles are assigned to Amazon EC2 instances.

Also, note that assuming an IAM Role can actually provide *more* permissions that originally available. `User1` could assume a role to obtain permission to Terminate an instance, which they are not permitted to do themselves. Therefore, it is important to control *who* is allowed to call `AssumeRole` or use `PassRole` (which is used to assign IAM Roles to services like EC2 and Lambda), otherwise they might gain more permissions that you want them to have.

Comment: I understood everything you wrote (I think), but I still don't understand how it answers my question, as to what you can do with roles that you cannot do with groups.  In your second bullet point, "Admin-Role is an IAM Role that has permission to Terminate EC2 instances", why can't I just create an IAM group that has permission to Terminate EC2 instances, and then add User1 to that IAM group?

Comment: If you are using an AWS account for yourself, then feel free to give yourself all permissions. If an account is being used in an organization with multiple users, it is vital to manage what permissions people have. There are some situations that _only_ accept IAM Roles (eg Lambda functions, EC2 instances). Also, using cross-account permissions requires assuming a role in a different account. For other situations, feel free to simply use your IAM User.

Comment: OK I think I understand this too, but I'm missing something fundamental about why it is this way.  For example, the statement that Lambda functions and EC2 instances only accept IAM Roles.  Why couldn't they have been designed to accept permissions granted to IAM user groups, just like other resources?  And same question about cross-account permissions -- why does my IAM user under account X have to assume a role in order to use a resource in account Y?  Why can't the resource in account Y have permissions granted to an IAM group in account X?

Comment: _"Why can't the resource in account Y have permissions granted to an IAM group in account X?"_ Where would you put those permissions? While some services (S3, SQS, SNS) have the ability to grant permissions, most services simply use permissions provided by IAM. IAM Roles do seem a little strange at first, but they do provide some great capabilities that IAM Users cannot enable.

Comment: 'Where would you put those permissions?'  I don't understand the question.  For a resource in group Y, if am allowed to say that some role has permission to access the resource and then grant users permission to assume that role, why can't I just say that an IAM group has permission to access the resource and then add users to that IAM group?  'Where would you put those permissions?'  The same 'place' that I would put the role permissions, presumably.

Comment: It is not possible to add IAM Users in Account-A to IAM Groups in Account-B.

Comment: OK, I understand that too, but I don't understand why you cannot add permissions on an EC2 instance in Account-A to an IAM Group in Account-B (which in turn would contain IAM users in Account-B).  Why on Earth would AWS make it possible to let IAM users in Account-B assume a *role* in Account-A (to access the EC2 instance), when it would be much simpler to just let an IAM Group in Account-B access the EC2 instance?  There must be some simple piece of information distinguishing the two that I'm not getting.