# why do you need roles (as opposed to IAM groups) to access resources in another AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am trying to understand why you need IAM "roles" to access a resource in a different IAM account, and why AWS can't just do the same thing with IAM groups.

Whenever I ask people this question the conversation just seems to go in circles:
Them: "To grant access to a resource to users in another IAM account, you have to give them permission to assume an IAM role, and then grant that IAM role access to your resource."
Me: "I understand that, but why can't you just create an IAM group that can access that resource, and then add those users from the other account to your IAM group?"
Them: "You can't add users from another AWS account to an IAM group in your account."
Me: "I understand that too, but why does AWS only let you do cross-account permissions like that by using roles?  Why wouldn't it make just as much sense for AWS to let you create an IAM group and then let you add IAM users from other accounts into that group?"

There's probably some simple one-sentence piece of information that explains why it has to be this way, and once someone tells you, it all makes sense, but it's not in the documentation and I don't know what it is.  What is it?

Comment: Similar to earlier question: [amazon web services - what can you do with IAM roles that you cannot do with IAM groups? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63198514/what-can-you-do-with-iam-roles-that-you-cannot-do-with-iam-groups)

Answer (score 0):

I would say security is main reason. IAM roles provide only **temporary** credentials. Using such credentials whenever possible is **good practice** for security reasons.

Off course you can also create IAM user in your account, and give the associated  access keys to people form the other account. And sometimes this is preferred, e.g. to enable read access only to some resources. But the issue is that IAM user credentials are **permanent**, unless manually disabled or deleted. For security reasons giving away permanent credentials to your account is not a recommended practice.

From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_common-scenarios_aws-accounts.html):

> We recommend using this approach to enforce the **principle of least privilege**. That means restricting the use of elevated permissions to only those times when they are needed for specific tasks. **With roles** you can help prevent accidental changes to sensitive environments, especially if you combine them with auditing to help ensure that roles are only used when needed.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but it seems to just lead to the same question: If I create a role in account A, and I grant a user in account B the permission to *assume* that role, aren't those *permissions* permanent (until I disable or delete them), even if the credentials are temporary?  So they get the temporary credentials, they use them, the credentials expire, but then they just get new ones.  So this seems equivalent to if I had the ability to grant semi-permanent permissions to the IAM users directly.  What am I missing?

Comment: @Bennett Hi. They key difference is that they have to explicitly assume the role. Since the role gives temprorary access (e.g. 1 hour) this not only limits what they can do during this span time, but also reduces the risk associated with exposing the credentials to a third party. The basic example is committing the credentials to a public git repo. The credentials would be valid for only 1h, whereas IAM users credentials would be permanent.

Comment: But I still don't see how this is less risky than just granting permissions to an IAM user in another account.  Scenario 1: You grant permissions to the IAM user in another account.  An attacker can get in only if they steal that user's credentials.  Scenario 2: You grant permissions to a role and let a user in another account assume that role.  Now an attacker can get in if they steal the temp. role credentials _or_ if they steal that user's credentials.  How can Scenario 2 possibly be more secure than Scenario 1?

Comment: @Bennett In your scenario it does not matter. But there are others. Would you prefer the user in the other account accidentally expose IAM permanent credentials to your account in a public githbut repo, or rather a temporary credentials valid for only 15 minutes for instance?

Comment: but I'm not saying "I create a new IAM user in my account A who can access the resource, and I give the credentials to a user in account B."  I'm saying "I grant permissions on this resource directly to a user in account B."  The usual objection is "AWS doesn't let you grant permissions on a resource to a user in another account."  I understand that, but then why on earth would AWS let you create a role and then directly grant a user in another account permissions to assume that role, but not let you grant them permissions to access the resource?

Comment: @Bennett I think some of these questions you would have to ask AWS directly. Its their design choice. I can't comment more on that, as I don't know why it was designed this way.

Answer (score 0):

The one-sentence answer is that Amazon chose to do it that way.

From an operational perspective, it simplifies life considerably if you associate an access key with an account. The alternative is to specify an account separately with every request.

From an organization management perspective, trees are easier to understand than forests. What I mean by that is that everything branches off the account's IAM root. If you  allow arbitrary users across the AWS universe to have access to arbitrary resources within arbitrary accounts, you end up with a management nightmare.

As a sidebar to that last comment, the early AWS services had resource-based policies. These are now discouraged in favor of identity-based policies, and newer services don't have resource policies.

Lastly, from a security perspective, a multi-tenant environment is a lot easier to control if you establish a hard wall around each tenant.

Comment: I understand what you wrote (I think) but I still don't understand why granting permissions on roles doesn't just give you the equivalent problem.  It sounds like you're saying it would be a "management nightmare" if resources in account A could have permissions granted to an IAM group in account A which could include IAM users in account B.  OK, why is it any less of a nightmare if resources in account A can have permissions granted to a role in account A, and then users in account B can have permission to assume that role?  Why isn't that exactly equivalent?

Comment: @Bennett - the "management nightmare" referred to resource-based policies.

Comment: There is still a lot of pain if you're looking at arbitrary users assigned to groups: how do you know what accounts those users belong to? At least with roles you have an account number as part of the trust policy.